# What META-tag should I use to specify British English language? (Open Graph)

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta, microdata

I use Open Graph on my website. How may I specify the British English language?
`<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />`or
`<meta property="og:locale" content="en_UK" />` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Comment: @JohnConde — This is very much a programming question, even if the motivation is SEO related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en-GB is mentioned for British English on ogp.me.